# Fan light kit leaves me perplexed

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling-fan

Two ceiling fans with light kit and remote on single wall switch. All worked well for 3 months. One light kit stopped working but fan worked. I replaced the light kit, the receiver (inside motor housing for remote), and now the ENTIRE fan. The light still doesn't work. The other fan and light still work fine. Could this be a deeper wiring issue to cause the light not to work but the fan to still get power?

Rejuvenation (Fanimation) Peregrine fan. One white, one black and one green wire on box and fan sides.

**Update:**

I didn't take photos of the wiring in the box but the ceiling box and fan both had a white, black and green. It was pretty straight forward. I thought both white and black needed the connection to power the fan, so if it's working those wires are ok.

I'm wondering about the molded connector (based on comment). Could it be bad on two entire fans? This may be a question for the manufacturer (they are helpful).

The model is the Rejuvenation (Fanimation) Peregrine fan. When I said receiver I did mean the remote receiver that is inside the motor housing. I will adjust original post.

Mostly I'm curious if this could be a deeper wiring issue upstream of the fan or if that isn't possible. Sure seems to be an internal fan problem but after taking the thing down four times now...ugh

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in both boxes involved please?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please [edit] your question to add some details. Include the make & model of the fan (that always helps). Also, you say "Receiver" that means that either the fan, the lights, or both are remote control - please indicate that. Did you double check _all_ the wiring to ensure that every wire nut was nice and tight and that no wires had come loose? Once you've done that, take the [tour] and browse the [help] to learn how to get the most out of this site while you're waiting for an answer.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue once.  The light worked periodically, then failed after a few months.  I replaced the light and the new one didn't work at all.  As it turns out the problem was a molded connector that came with the fan/light.  It wasn't making a good connection.  I cut it off and used wire nuts.  Everything worked fine after that.

Comment: Are the fans wired to always-hot power, an ordinary wall switch, or something more sophisticated?

Comment: What molded connector are you concerned about? Are there internal connections in the fan (between the fan & light kit maybe) that have connectors instead of bare wires? While it's a major hassle to take the fan apart for the 5th time, doing so and getting pics may help someone spot an issue that you're not seeing.

Comment: Also, can you confirm that [this is the fan/light](https://www.rejuvenation.com/catalog/collections/peregrine-industrial-LED-ceiling-fans) you're talking about? If so, here are the [installation instructions](https://d3o372dlsg9lxo.cloudfront.net/uploads/product/pdf_installation_instructions/5304e74001925b32630010e2/Peregrine___ENG_SPA__OM_03_27_15_final_.pdf). Actually, I don't see anywhere in there about any actual wiring to the light kit. It shows the light kit, but not even how to mount it. Which is... odd.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct fan. The light kit is a plug and play with plastic connectors. I wiggled and jiggled and pushed and pulled with the electric on and that light never changed. As mentioned, at one point the light worked fine and it suddenly stopped and hasn't worked again since, even with the replacements. I think cutting off the plastic clip and using wire nuts might be a good idea. That is easier to take off than the whole fan anyway.

They are wired to a ordinary wall switch and have a remote.